# fpdf2 write - how to get new lines printed instead of '\n'?

Tags: python, fpdf

I want to print some text in my pdf as follows;

```
text = self.dict_text_for_pdf[category]
self.pdf.write(_c.text_line_height, text)
```

Inside the text I have some line break characters. But instead of a new line being printed I actually get "\n" printed instead. According to the documents this should work; https://py-pdf.github.io/fpdf2/LineBreaks.html. How do I fix this?

Comment: *"How do I fix this?"* By using a real line feed character, not a literal \ followed by an n.

Comment: I am sure you are right. But could you elaborate, my Google searches are not helping me? What should I be putting in instead?